# How getting on which validator a specific nominator was before the historyDepth?

Tags: polkadot, rewards

I'm trying to `rebuild` part of my `database` thanks to `events and extrinsics,` i managed to get it partly all , but i'm stuck with this one :

```
How to know on which validator a nominator was ?
```

I tried to look to events but, apart the rewards amount, nothing point to which validator he was on, i tried  to look in extrinsics, i found the payoutStakers but it doesn't give me the information too.

My guess was, to be able to look for a transaction to the nominator from the validator stash address from where he was rewarded...

Does it seems logic ? Or anyone would have another idea ?

Thanks a lot and have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the `at` param. You can query the state of a specific block height. You can get the storage data at any timepoint.

https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc#getstoragekey-storagekey-at-blockhash-storagedata

[image]
[image]

Comment: so what you're suggesting is maybe to get the blockhash of the rewarded event and look into the storage data of this specific block ?